# Having trouble clearing "selected" attributes from my select menu list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I'm using jQuery 1.9.  How do I clear all selected attributes from a select menu?  I'm tryihng this

```
$(".countryField option").prop("selected", false)
```

but it is not working.  As evidence, here is what is output in my console ...

```
> $('.countryField').length
1
> $(".countryField option").prop("selected", false)
jQuery.fn.init[255]
> $('.countryField').find('option[selected="selected"]')
[<option value=​"233" selected=​"selected">​United States​</option>​, <option selected=​"selected" value=​"233">​United States​</option>​]
```

Note that right after I invoke the statement that is supposed to clear the selected items, I look for options taht are selected and promptly find two.  How can I clear the selected options once and for all?

Comment: What is the default or first option in the select? Is it going back to that?

Comment: you could set the index of the select to -1, although that seems like a bit of a hack ... https://jsfiddle.net/hajug3vo/

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try (in order):

1. Instead of `.prop()`, try `.removeAttr('selected')`
2. If that doesn't work, the issue you have is that you're `<option>s`exist in a `<select>` and select boxes will always default to the first available option. So you can have an "filler" `<option value="">Select Country</option>` to catch the default.